# addBetweenCondition today not returning

Tags: php, yii

I tried a couple of ways. It's not returning the correct number. It either gives me the default number which is set at the beginning or returns the searched criteria but ignores the store_id.

```
        $percent = 8;
        $today = date('Y-m-d');

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->compare('store_id', 253);
//      $criteria->condition = 'store_id=:store_id';
//      $criteria->params = array('store_id'=>253);
//      the bottom addcondition ignores that store id, and gives me what it finds btwn dates
//      $criteria->addCondition = 'CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN date_from AND date_to'; 
//      addbetweencondition doesn't find anything between dates
        $criteria->addBetweenCondition($today, 'date_from', 'date_to');
        $override = Model::model()->find($criteria);
        if ($override) {
            $override_percent= $override->percent/100;
        }
        print_r ($override_percent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `addBetweenCondition` wrong. The first three parameters should be:

- the column to match against
- the start date
- the end date

I think it should be something like the code below (untested):

```
$date_from = date('Y-m-d');
$date_to = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('column_name_that_contains_date', $date_from, $date_to);
```

Read more about the function:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addBetweenCondition-detail

Comment: ah that's right,.. but my column name is not really a column but today's date, so how would that work?

Comment: The column name is always the current (todays) date?

Comment: hmm, no. The column is the date from and date to. Im guessing `addbetweencondition` doesn't work here then.